# How much is the actual width?

Tags: html, css

The question is this ->> an html element has these styles width: 150px; padding: 3px; border: 4px; margin: 7px; How much is the real width...

I can't get the question because it's said that the width is 150 px.. so why are they asking this ?

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would say, 154px is the real width because border adds 4px to 150px but padding and margin don't make a different to an elements actual width.

Comment: Depends what you define under *real width* and what you've set `box-sizing` to.

Comment: a friend of mine says that the real width in this case would be 156 because width += 2*padding

Comment: @codeAddicted — As Bram said, it depends on what "real" means (and the values of various other properties, e.g. `display`).

Comment: @RichardMacarthy You are incorrect, absent a `box-sizing` declaration `padding` **does** increase width as do borders.. - See - https://jsfiddle.net/mzwhm6x2/1/

Comment: See this reference site - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: you may do some reading at the W3C to find out some explanation:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html and

http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-css3-ui-20150310/#propdef-box-sizing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absent a `box-sizing` declaration padding does increase width as do borders..

So in your example

150px **internal content** width + 6px of padding (right & left 3px) **plus** 8px of border (right and left 4px) = 164px.

The default box-sizing setting is `content-box`

> content-box
>   .This is the default style as specified by the CSS standard. The width and height properties are measured including only the content, but not the padding, border or margin. Note: Padding, border & margin will be outside of the box e.g. IF .box {width: 350px}; THEN you apply {border: 10px solid black;} RESULT {rendered in the browser} .box {width: 370px;}

[**MDN reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

```css
div {
  width: 150px;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 7px;
  border: 4px solid red;
  padding: 3px;
  background:lightblue;
}
.nopadding {
  padding: 0;
  border-color:green;
}
.box {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-color:rebeccapurple;
}
```

```html
<div></div>

<div class="nopadding"></div>

<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: soo, u are saying that we don't include margin in our calculations ?

Comment: Nope...margins keep elements apart...they don't add to widths.

Comment: Then why here it says we calculate margin too ->> http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp